# finding all missing letters from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Below is my code to find a missing letter in an array:

```js
function missingletter(str) {
  var nums = str.split('').map(function(letter){
    return letter.charCodeAt();
  })
  
  for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i+1] - nums[i] >1){
      return String.fromCharCode(nums[i]+1)
    }
  }
  return undefined
}

missingletter("abce");
```

The for loop in the function stops when it finds a missing letter immediately.

How should I revise this code if I want to make the loop go through every element in an array and return every missing letter? For example, getting a return value of 'd', 'f', 'i' with missingletter("abceghj").

Comment: @mplungjan hmm then it prints 'undefined'

Comment: I made a version of this answer that works for strings that aren't in alphabetical order and that contain more than one missing character in between. https://codepen.io/marcusparsons/pen/YYxrpG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to NOT return each letter from the function but return an array or string instead

```js
function missingletter(str) {
  var missing = [], nums = str.split('').map(function(letter){
    return letter.charCodeAt();
  })
  
  for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i+1] - nums[i] >1){
      missing.push(String.fromCharCode(nums[i]+1))
    }
  }
  return missing
}

console.log(missingletter("abce"));
console.log(missingletter("abceghj"));
```

To have a more solid solution that can handle duplicates and wrong order have a look at Marcus' solution here: https://codepen.io/marcusparsons/pen/YYxrpG

Comment: thanks so much! another quick question. when i type //return missing.push(String.fromCharCode(nums[i]+1))// in the for loop, it prints 1. could you explain?

Comment: Why would you return the result of the push? That is the length of the array

Comment: i was just curious to know, have been playing with this code. so the it returns the length of the value, and is 1 because it stopped when it found 'd'?

Comment: Yes - that is correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: The return will leave the function immediately

Comment: See the link I posted

Comment: Even this is wrong, however, because it doesn't account for multiple missing letters in between characters or if the string is out of order.  See my example: https://codepen.io/marcusparsons/pen/YYxrpG

Comment: That is only wrong in case of multiple letters

Comment: No, it is also wrong if the letters are out of order, as well.  The output for: `console.log(missingletter("cbae"));` is `["b"]` which is incorrect.

Comment: So we need to sort before comparing

Comment: Precisely.  And take a look at how I handled multiple character includes.  Feel free to add it to your answer and modify as you see fit! :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning immediately, you need to store the values, in an array or string and return it at the end

```js
function missingletter(str) {
  var nums = str.split('').map(function(letter){
    return letter.charCodeAt();
  })
  const mis = [];
  for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i+1] - nums[i] >1){
      mis.push(String.fromCharCode(nums[i]+1))
    }
  }
  return mis
}

console.log(missingletter("abcegi"));
```

Comment: Beat you by 20 secs ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't return more than one value so to return a collection of values it has to be either an array or a string. The simplest modification of your function as it stands would be to push the found values to an array.

```
function missingletter(str) {
  var result = [];
  var nums = str.split('').map(function(letter){
    return letter.charCodeAt();
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i + 1] - nums[i] > 1) {
      result.push(String.fromCharCode(nums[i]+1));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Already answered twice